# I want to add class to some div's when I hit the same button second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am removing the `btn` class after I hit it for the first time and adding new class to it. When I hit second time with `btn1` class it's not adding any class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.fC').addClass('fCr');
    $('.sC').addClass('sCr');
    $('.btn').addClass('btn1').removeClass('btn');
});
$('.btn1').click(function(){
    $('.tC').addClass('tCr');
    $('.sC').addClass('fCr');
});
</script>
```

Comment: @das-g they're also using  addclass() and removeClass() and chaining functions - so I think that's it's safe to say that it's jQuery

Comment: I believe you will have to use delegates. Try `$(".btn").on("click", function(){})` or `$(document).on("click", ".btn", function(){})`

Comment: There are other solution of it, if you need then i can make an answer.

Comment: Ya sure Frayne Konok whats that?